# Convert string to proper URI format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Is there any easy way to convert email address string into proper URI format?

Input:

```
http://mywebsite.com/validate_email/3DE4ED727750215D957F8A1E4B117C38E7250C33/myemail@yahoo.com
```

Output should be:

```
http://mywebsite.com/validate_email/3DE4ED727750215D957F8A1E4B117C38E7250C33/myemail%40yahoo.com
```

If I didn't do the output, I get an error response like

```
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you tried [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)?

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode will encode the '/' also. HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode will help here.

Comment: @mhm I mean to encode just email address.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Description

You have to extract your QueryString from the url, encode them and build the new url.

#### Sample

```
string url = "http://mywebsite.com/validate_email/3DE4ED727750215D957F8A1E4B117C38E7250C33/myemail@yahoo.com";
int index = url.LastIndexOf("/");

string queryString = url.Substring(index + 1, url.Length - (index + 1));
url = url.Substring(0, index) + "/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryString);

// url is now
// http://mywebsite.com/validate_email/3DE4ED727750215D957F8A1E4B117C38E7250C33/myemail%40yahoo.com
```

#### More Information

- [String.LastIndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx)
- [String.Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)
- [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)